# Make two data sets have the same standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have two different data sets A and B (37 elements each and they have the same mean), and I would like to modify B to have the same standard deviation as A.

I figured to make both have the same mean, I'd have to multiply each element of B by mean(a)/mean(b). But how to make them have the same spread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out meanwhile, sorry for a quickly closed post ^^

Here is the formula for anyone interested:

$$B = \frac{stDev(A)}{stDev(B)} (B - mean(B)) + mean(B)$$

stdev(S) = Standard Deviation of S

Comment: What is your reasoning?

Comment: Totally Just a hunch. I tested it out in a plotting website and it turned out to be exact.

Comment: The LHS is the modified value of set B?

Comment: Yes, basically every element in B should be multiplied by the RHS

Comment: There are several flaws in my view. For instance, you basically divide the value of set B by standard deviation of set A and multiply it be standard deviation of set B. It should be the other way round. You can check the method by using two small sets. For instance: $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,3,5\}$.

Comment: The formula works with the sets you suggested as well, I just tested it out.
Could you check your calculations ?

Comment: Oh I'm totally sorry you're right, when I use the formula I use the correct one with B on the bottom and A on top, but I wrote it wrong in here my bad you are totally correct